# What's the difference between markers and problems view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

What's the difference between `markers` and `problems` view in Eclipse?

Most of the time, their contents are the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Markers view shows all the different types of marker that Eclipse supports - problems, tasks, bookmarks, ...

The Problems view just shows problem markers.

The Tasks view just shows task markers.

The Bookmarks view just shows bookmark markers.